# Does Leixia's weapon clash get through instead of bouncing back?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

It seems like every time there is a weapon clash between Leixia and another character, her's gets through while the opponent's bounces back. Does Leixia get some kind of priority because of her style?

[image: (not a weapon clash)]

Answer (score 1):

Leixia's weapon clashes do not get any sort of advantage over other characters - a clash is a clash. Depending on the amount of damage an attack does, however, a weapon clash may leave you and your opponent "reeling" (the brief stun as the characters ready their weapons again). Since Leixia's attacks do not do a huge amount of damage, her weapon clashes will not typically cause said stun, which means the second hit of a combo (e.g. `A.A` or `B.B`) may still be executed, which will often end up with you damaging your opponent.

Comment: I've seen this happen again with her regular [A] move. I'll try to test this and see if I can come up with something definitive.