# What triggers a weapon clash?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

While testing various timings and attacks for [Does Leixia's weapon clash get through instead of bouncing back?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50602/does-leixias-weapon-clash-get-through-instead-of-bouncing-back) I've found that not all attacks that occur at the same time will clash. This is obvious when I think about it, but it has me wondering - what triggers a weapon clash?

Do the two attacks have to be the same alignment (low, mid, high)? Do they need to be the same type of attack (i.e. will an `A` clash a `B`, or a `A+B` clash a `B+K`)? How does attack damage factor in? What makes a character "reel" after a weapon clash, instead of continuing an attack?

Comment: On a side note: I remember from older soul calibur games that the vertical slash would always beat out the horizontal slash in a weapon clash. I'm not sure if that's still the same.